# SQL datediff - People older than

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table called member in which I have member information and in that information, their birth date.

I need to get a list of all the people that are more than 25 years old. For now, I got this :

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, birthday, GETDATE() ) > 25
```

The only thing is that it doesn't take into consideration all the people that turned 25 this year so far...

How do I add to this everyone that turned 25 in January and February of this year as well ?

Would someone be able to help me out ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does `DATEDIFF(year, birthday, GETDATE() ) >= 25` return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `datediff()`.  Just subtract the years from the current date:

```
where birthday < dateadd(year, -25, getdate())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 25 years to their birthday and then comparing to now.  If <=, then they are older than 25.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM members
    WHERE DATEADD(year, 25, birthday) <= getdate()
```